# Failure on findViewById on an android application

Tags: java, android

So, starting with Android and Java, and I have this baffling error: The application fails with a stopped unexpectedly message when reaches a findViewByID(R.id.answer) but only if I add another one to the code.

The code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/site" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/site" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- 
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/username" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/username" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
   -->
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/password" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/password" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/question" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/question" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/answer" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/answer" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <Button android:id="@+id/confirm" 
          android:text="@string/confirm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

OnCreate method

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.keyedit);
 setTitle(R.string.edit_entry);
 mDbHelper = new KeyRingDbAdapter(this);
 mDbHelper.open();
 mSiteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.site);
 //mUsernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
 mPasswordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
 mQuestionText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
 mAnswerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
```

So, the above works and the line `mAnswerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);` assigns the right object to `mAnswerText`. Once I uncomment the code, that same line, that has worked before, fails. When I see the xml on the graphical layout, all appears correctly. The R file seems to be ok (I deleted it and go it regenerated, just in case).

Any ideas? Any more info needed?

EDIT: Well, awkward. Last night I got home and, when I uncommented the lines, this time it worked. I am experienced enough as programmer and I did enough checking to know that it wasn't me just uncommenting part or doing something else entirely stupid. Though it could have been something related to the fact that I am new to Eclipse as well. Not cool, as right now the error has been fixed "magically" and I am not the wiser.

Comment: You've commented both java code and the element in the xml file - so, just to be sure, the application fails if you uncomment *both* sections (not just the line in the java code) !?

Comment: Please post the full logcat error message.

Comment: @Andreas_D yes, uncommenting both.

Comment: @Haphazard Can't access it right now. Once I do I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue today. In a RelativeLayout I reordered the layout xml file - and got this error.

I cleaned the project (Eclipse: Project / Clean) et voilà it worked again.

Eclipse help: "Clean - This command discards all previous build results. If autobuild is on, then this invokes a full build."

Answer (score 0):

Sure you imported the right R? there are two of them, make sure you not imported the wrong one...

Comment: I will check. But, if I imported the wrong one the commented line will be the one failing as it has the new id, not the one that the id had worked already. Wouldn't that be the case?

Comment: yes, you're right... But that happened to me a view times, that's why I wanted to mention it ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure I will find that kind of issues in the future, so I will keep that nugget of information :-)